# Data cost of keeping a tcp connection open

Tags: tcp

Let's suppose 2 computers:

- The first is running a netcat server on a tcp port.
- The second is running a netcat client, connected to the previous netcat server.

(netcat is an example, you can imagine a basic c program with socket)

We ca send data between the 2 computers.

Let's imagine nobody send data during multiple days.

Is there a timeout in tcp stack ?

Does netcat (or operating system) sends some packets to keep the connection opened ?

What i want to know is how much data is sent if there is no top level activity.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Not unless an intermediate router drops the connection. 2. Netcat: no; operating system: only if TCP keepalive has been enabled - it is off by default, and its default interval when on is 2 hours. So the data costs are either zero or neglilgible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a timeout in tcp stack ?

There are many different timeouts in the TCP stack, depending on what state we are currently in, and how the connection was configured (e.g. with keepalive or not). The idle connection timeout (which is what you refer to) does not seem to be defined. With keepalive the timeout is ~2 hours. That being said pretty much every firewall in the world will setup some timeout. Based on [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/26256h/tcp_session_idle_timeouts/) 15 minutes looks like a reasonable assumption, maybe even 1 hour. But multiple days? I doubt it will be alive in any network (except your own).

> Does netcat (or operating system) sends some packets to keep the connection opened ?

No. You will have to do it yourself by sending data. With the keepalive option for TCP, the OS will do it for you (note: keepalive is disabled by default), but this works between direct peers, i.e. may fail when proxies are involved. Sending data is definitely a better approach.

Comment: No. The 'exact number' is infinite, not 'implementation-dependent', unless TCP keepalive has been enabled on the socket, in which case it is 120 *minutes* by default. See RFCs 793, 1122, 1123. The claim that Windows will timeout a connection after 120s is baseless.

Comment: Which RFC exactly states that it isn't infinite? Which RFC states that TCP connections can time out when idle? This is your contention. Support it. And the answer to 'who cares' is that if you aren't RFC-compliant you are not permitted to connect to the Internet.

Comment: @user207421 fair enough, RFC 5482 `In the absence of an application-specified user timeout, the TCP specification [RFC0793] defines a default user timeout of 5 minutes.` I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user207421 lol, and who exactly will stop me from connecting to the internet, even when I am not RFC-compliant? Get real. Not to mention that most implementations (of pretty much everything) out there are not fully RFC-compliant.

Comment: The timeout cited from RFC 793 is for data transmission, not for idle connections. As is the entirety of RFC 5482: 'The TCP user timeout controls how long transmitted data may remain unacknowledged before a connection is forcefully closed'. As for connecting to the Internet, ho is going to let you? Your ISP won't. They provide the modem, which is RFC-compliant. You can only connect to your modem.

Comment: @user207421 so ISP is going to prevent me from connecting to the internet because I set timeout to 5min instead of infinity? How exactly he is going to check that? And why would he even do that? I really don't know where are you going with this argument.

Comment: The ISP doesn't *have* to prevent it, he just doesn't give you any way of *doing* it. You can only connect to the router. The router connects to the Internet. I've already stated that. The RFC system is there for a purpose. Otherwise what would be the point? And you still haven't addressed my initial comment.

Comment: @user207421 listen, "doesn't give a way of doing it" and "preventing it" is the same thing. My question remains: does ISP allow me to connect to the internet if I am not RFC-compliant about timeouts? The answer is "yes, it does" and lets end this discussion. You are overrating RFCs, which are just documents. With overall good ideas, but often lagging behind the evolving world. Let me give you a concrete example: I don't know a single email provider that accepts all email formats defined in RFCs, e.g. which email provider allows whitespaces in emails? That's the reality, not RFC.

Comment: @user207421 but I admit that I misread the RFC 5482. You may be right about no timeout defined in any RFC. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The answer is no. You can only connect to your router. Your router connects to the internet. RFC 1122 and 1123 are entitled 'requirements for Internet Hosts', and that includes edge routers - but it doesn't include what's behind them. And 'The idle connection timeout (which is what you refer to) does not seem to be defined' is not accurate. What is accurate is '*no* idle timeout is defined'.